# Can I export two different material applied for inside and outside the 3d model to gltf file?

Tags: texturing, gltf

I'm fairly new to Blender.

I'm trying to apply two different textures to the inside and outside of a 3D model and then export it to a glTF file for use in a VR environment.

I understand that I need to use the 'backfacing' option of the Geometry within the Shader Editor to apply different textures to opposite sides of the model. However, when I export it to glTF, it consistently shows only one texture applied to both the inside and outside.

I attempted to solidify the model so that it has two distinct sides to which I can attach the textures, but in UV editing mode, I only found one side available for pasting the texture.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? I work with a.frame for a VR environment.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance in resolving this matter.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Answer (score 1):

Click "Apply" on the Solidify modifier.  Then you can apply different materials or textures to the resulting geometry.

[image: screenshot of applying a modifier]